# Core Data NSString works NSNumber does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm developing an app on iOS in Objective-C. 
I'm trying to use Core Data but I'm getting a really weird issue.

```
@interface Food : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * bought;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;

@end
```

/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
Food* newFood = (Food*)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSLog(@"%@", newFood.name);
NSLog(@"%d", [newFood.quantity intValue]);
```

This will print the name, but will give me an error on the quantity.
I have tried many different things and I don't know what the problem is.
I did not change the data model or do anything different in between the string and the number.
I even remade everything in a new project and same thing.

Here is the error :

```
2015-06-22 13:05:22.219 Test[50408:2682580] Food
2015-06-22 13:05:22.219 Test[50408:2682580] -[NSEntityDescription         quantity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb7ae24a60
2015-06-22 13:05:22.221 Test[50408:2682580] *** Terminating app     due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [NSEntityDescription quantity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb7ae24a60'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, are you trying to insert new object or fetch one from the store ?

Comment: I checked the data model and it is defined in the data model and I also used the editor tab from the data model to make the Food class. Any other ideas?

Comment: I will be trying to insert a new object into the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting back an `NSManagedObject` subclass `Food`, you are getting an `NSEntityDescription`.

You don't want `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` you want `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.

Explanation of your odd debug info:

The reason the `name` property works is because that is a property of `NSEntityDescription`. Change your `Food` property to `foodName` and watch what happens. The `name` call will still work.

Comment: Wow worked like a charm. Thank you been at this for 2 days. Never want to use lynda.com again haha. One last question. Does this automatically save when using the insertNewObject? or would have still have to call saveContext from the delegate?

Comment: You have to save the context! There is no autosave.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a NSEntityDescription instance, that just describes (hence the name) an entity. But instead of using it, you brutally cast that to the desired Class, but casting only tells the compiler to shut up, it does not magically convert something into anything else.

NSEntityDescription happens to have a name attribute, that is why that line works.

try

```
Food *newFood = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Food" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

---

From the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html)

- > #### The Entity Description
  >
  > An entity description specifies (amongst other things) the name of an entity, the class used to represent the
  >   entity, and the entity’s properties. The entity description is
  >   important since a given class may be used to represent more than one
  >   entity—by default all entities are represented by NSManagedObject.
  >   Core Data uses the entity description to determine what properties a
  >   managed object has, what needs to be saved to or retrieved from the
  >   persistent store, and what constraints there are on property values.
  >   Entity descriptions are properties of a managed object model.
- > #### Creating a Managed Object
  >
  > Fundamentally NSManagedObject is an Objective-C class like any other
  >   Objective-C class. Like various other classes, NSManagedObject imposes
  >   some constraints on instance creation. As described earlier, you must
  >   associate the new managed object instance with the entity object that
  >   defines its properties and with the managed object context that
  >   defines its environment. You cannot therefore initialize a managed
  >   object simply by sending an init message, you must use the designated
  >   initializer — `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`—which sets
  >   both the entity and context:
  >
  > ```
  > NSManagedObject *newEmployee = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:employeeEntity
  >                                          insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
  > ```

---

Some more observations:

- Nowadays I expect Objective-C/Cocoa(-touch) code to be using Automatic Reference Counting, in that the `retain` attribute for properties should be exchanged with `strong`
- for NSString properties you almost certainly want `copy` instead of `strong`

---

- > Does this automatically save when using the insertNewObject?

No, as this could lead to not fully populated object in the store depending on your model & app logic.

- > or would have still have to call saveContext from the delegate?

Where and when to save depends on your app logic.